# Java Mail unable to find valid certification path

Tags: java, ssl, gmail, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to make a gmail client for Windows to learn Swing and I have a problem using JavaMail to read emails with IMAP.

I've seen many threads about this problem and most of them say I have to add the certification path to the JRE.

I got the certificate with openssl and added it to the keystore but I keep getting the same error :

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Here is my code :

```java
final String username = setting.getAddress();
final String password = setting.getPassword();
String receivingHost="imap.gmail.com";//for imap protocol

Properties props2=System.getProperties();
props2.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

Session session2=Session.getDefaultInstance(props2, null);
try {
    Store store=session2.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect(receivingHost,username, password);
    Folder folder=store.getFolder("INBOX");//get inbox
    folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);//open folder only to read
    Message message[]=folder.getMessages();
    for(int i=0;i<message.length;i++){
        System.out.println(message[i].getSubject());
    }

    folder.close(true);
    store.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```